# Lambda Calculus Evaluate: First Reduce expression and then substitute?

Tags: haskell, lambda, lambda-calculus

I am starting learning haskell and today in my class our teacher has resolved an excercise which we have to subtitute the expressions given. One of those expressions which was resolved by the teacher was the following:

```
(\ x. x) (\ y. y + x) [x: = z + z]
(\ x. x) (\ y. y + (z + z))
```

It seems that the teacher only replaced the free x on the right with the new value asked, but it didn't reduce the expression. What i see on this expression `(\ x. x) (\ y. y + x)` its that is a Redox. So what i would do first is reduce and then substitute.

So in my notebook i wrote this steps to get the solution:

```
(\ x. x) (\ y. y + x) [x: = z + z]
(\ y. y + x) [x: = z + z]
(\ y. y + (z + z))
```

My doubt: is it my solution correct? Can i first Reduce expression and then substitute? Thanks

Comment: This depends on the actual question. If the question is "apply the substitution to this term", then you are not asked to beta-reduce the term: doing that is wrong since substitution does not involve reduction. If the question is "substitute and reduce" then after the substitution you have to beta-reduce. These are distinct exercises, so be careful about what the exercise is asking.

Comment: All right, thanks very much for your comment @chi. You have resolved my doubt